# A function parameter of type void

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it possible to make the following pseudo-code compile without defining an explicit specialization of `GetValue<void>`?

```
template <class Increment = void>
inline int GetValue(const Increment & inc = {})
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Increment, void>)
    {
        return 25;
    }
    else
    {
        return 25 + inc;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << GetValue(1) << std::endl; //compiles
    std::cout << GetValue() << std::endl;  //does not compile
}
```

In this pseudo-code I pass as GetValue parameter either a value by which I increment 25 constant or some value that indicates 'absolutely nothing'. And it is not clear enough what this 'absolutely nothing' is and how to represent it if a parameter of type `void` does not compile.

If I define a fake type like

```
struct Nothing {};
```

it probably looks like nothing, but not like 'absolutely nothing'.

Comment: C++ doesn't really have a "nothing" type, and doesn't have a "unit" type (it sort of has one, in the guise of [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) type for use with `std::variant` ... but that's more of a special case than broadly general purpose).

Comment: Your question would be greatly improved if you explained *why* you want this and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In your example, since you already have 2 code blocks in your `if constexpr`, you could just have a no-arg overload with the first block

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am trying to eliminate the need to specialize `GetValue<void>`, because in my real code `GetValue` has 10th of overloads and some overloads have nontrivial implementation. It would be probably easier to add an optional template parameter as in my pseudo-code and check if it is `void` or not with `if constexpr`

Comment: @Dmitriano You are saying it would be easier to add an optional template parameter to tens of overloads than to add one more overload??? You might have over-simplified your example code to the point where your issue is no longer apparent.

Comment: @JaMiT yes, I understand what you mean, but in my certain case I need something like 'template metaprogramming null` or 'template metaprogramming nothing`.

Comment: `struct Void {};` and then default the parameter to that instead of `void`.

Comment: @Dmitriano Oh, right. I get the feeling some of the details of this question are missing. People have offered a number of valid solutions, but you seem reluctant to accept any of them. This indicates that you example is too simplified and that there are considerations that are not apparent from it.

Comment: @super probably yes, the real-life code takes about 250 lines, but anyway as far as I see, the possible options are `struct Void {}` and variadic templates. I am thinking on what is better.

Answer (score 4):

No. You cannot have an object of type `void`. However, you don't need a specialization. All you need is an overload:

```
int GetValue()
{
    return 25;
}

template <class Increment>
int GetValue(const Increment& inc)
{
    return GetValue() + inc;
}
```

Your other option is to default the template parameter to something other than `void`:

```
template <class Increment = int>
int GetValue(const Increment& inc = {})
{
    return 25 + inc;
}
```

A `GetValue()` call then effectively becomes `GetValue(0)`, which also does the job.

Comment: @Dmitriano There is no `GetValue<void>` specialization here. Just a normal function overload.

Comment: It is not what I need. In my real code `GetValue` has non-trivial implementation and has 10th overloads, so declaring separate functions will result in code duplication.

Comment: @Dmitriano And two seperate `if constexpr` branches doesn't? If you have stuff before/after it (which then must be independant of the argument), you could probably extract that into another function

Comment: `if constexpr` does not, because I can add it into a few lines of code in the `GetValue` overloads implementation and I do not need to redeclare all the overloads.

Comment: @Dmitriano Well, OK. Added another way of doing it then.

Comment: zero is not nothing, it is concrete number, but I need absolutely nothing or some kind of template metaprogramming nullptr

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea based on variadic templates:

```
template <typename ...INCREMENT>
int GetValue(const INCREMENT &...inc) {
    // this "if" is not actually needed for this example, but if you want
    // to discriminate between zero/non-zero number of parameters,
    // it can be done this way
    if constexpr (sizeof...(inc) == 0) {
        return 25;
    } else {
        return (25 + ... + inc);
        // or you can use this:
        // const auto &i = (inc, ...);
        // return 25 + i;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout<<GetValue(1)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<GetValue()<<"\n";
}
```

Note that this solution allows any number of parameters. If you must have a zero or one parameter `GetValue`, I think that you can use SFINAE to only allow one parameter.

(for example, you can use `std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(INCREMENT)<=1, int>` as the return type of the function)

Comment: No SFINAE needed. A `static_assert(sizeof...(inc) <= 1)` will do. Also, regular `if` is enough here. No need for `if constexpr`.

Comment: @NikosC.: If the OP has other GetValue functions (with more than one parameters), then SFINAE is a better solution.